# call a function and loops in parallel

Tags: c++, openmp

I don't have any experience in openMP , so I want to kow how to do the following:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= NumImages; i++) {

//call a function
myfunction(...);

for (int k = 0 ; k < SumNumber k++) {

   for (int l = 0; l < ElNum ; l++) {

       //do 2 summing up calculations inside a while loop

  }//end k loop

}//end i loop
```

Now , I have 40 cores in my disposal.

NumImages will be from 50 to 150 ,more usual  150.

SumNumber will be around 200.

ElNum will be around 5000.

So , the best dealing with this is assigning every thread to a function call and also  execute in parallel the l loop?

And if yes  , it will be like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(40)

    for (int i = 1; i <= NumImages; i++) {

       myfunction(...);

        for (int k = 0 ; k < SumNumber k++) {

           #pragma omp for
           for (int l = 0; l < ElNum ; l++) {
```

And the above means (for NumImages = 150)  that myfunction will be executed 40 times in parallel and also l loop and then ,when l loop and k loop finishes , the next 40 threads will call again the function and the next 40 , so 3*40 = 120 and then the next 30?

Comment: Your snippet is not conforming to the standard as you have two nested worksharing regions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Generally the best way is the way that splits the work evenly, to maintain efficiency (no cores are waiting). E.g. in your case probably static scheduling is not a good idea, because 40 does not divide 150 evenly, for the last iteration you would loose 25% of computing power. So it might turn out, that it would be better to put `parallel` clause before second loop. It all the depends on the mode you choose, and how really work is distributed within loops. E.g., If `myfunction` does 99% then its a bad idea, if 99% of work is within 2 inner loops it might be good.
2. Not really. There are 3 scheduling modes. But none of them works in a way, that it blocks other threads. There is a pool of tasks (iterations) that is distributed among the threads. Scheduling mode describes the strategy of assigning tasks to threads. When one thread finishes, it just gets next task, no waiting. The strategies are described in more detail here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Scheduling_clauses (I am not sure if balant-copy paste from wiki is a good idea, so I'll leave a link. It's a good material.)

Maybe what is not written there is that the modes overhead are presented in order of the amount of overhead they introduce. `static` is fastest, then `dynamic`, then `guided`. My advice when to use which would be, this is not the exact best, but good rule of thumb IMO:

1. `static` if you know will be divided evenly among the threads and take the same amount of time
2. `dynamic` if you know the tasks will not be divided evenly or their execution times are not even
3. `guided` for rather long tasks that you pretty much cannot tell anything

If your tasks are rather small you can see an overhead even for static scheduling (E.g. [why my OpenMP C++ code is slower than a serial code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206176/why-my-openmp-c-code-is-slower-than-a-serial-code/15206781#15206781)), but I think in your case `dynamic` should be fine and best choice.

Comment: :Hello, so you are saying that if the most work is in the function call ,then leave pragma omp to the loop I have it .But if the most work is in the last loops ,then put pragma omp before second loop , right?And also use dynamic only  because I don't have evenly distributed data?

Comment: Well, yea. Generally always try to find a plan that will **distribute the workload evenly**, in this order `static`->`dynamic`->`guided`. There is nothing more that can be said in general IMO. I'd test a few approaches for a particular case. I don't know your program, bu I would put my bet that, current code + dynamic scheduling will be the best option. It really all depends on a case.

Comment: :Also , in my last loop (l loop) where I have sum+=.. ,do I have to put above sum the  pragma omp barrier?

Comment: I think it's redundant. How would you split work at this level? You could do 10 threads for the outer loop and then 4 for the inner if you wanted 2-level parallelization. But I don't think it will work very well for a simple summation.